# SpringBootApplication not loading in java class

Tags: spring-boot

I have created a java class and tried to import SpringBootApplication but does not work.

```
package com.imooc;

public class Application {

}
```

Below are my pom.xml for parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yizhen</groupId>
    <artifactId>yizhen-red-book-dev</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>book-common</module>
        <module>book-model</module>
        <module>book-mapper</module>
        <module>book-service</module>
        <module>book-api</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
    </parent>

... ...
```

Below are my build-install process, which seems to work fine:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] yizhen-red-book-dev ................................ SUCCESS [  0.420 s]
[INFO] book-common ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.695 s]
[INFO] book-model ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.065 s]
[INFO] book-mapper ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.065 s]
[INFO] book-service ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.053 s]
[INFO] book-api ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.732 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.551 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-28T22:42:06-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 40M/608M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[The Maven dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x84ji.png)

I tried refresh the Maven and rebuild but does not work.

Comment: are you creating the main class in parent or inside any of the module? If parent, try adding this dependency <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

Comment: can you add the project structure to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The spring boot project is different from a simple java project it is a maven project.

I reccomend either you can create a maven project and configure all the dependencies classes and folders which is very confusing and time taking

or the easier way used by almost all spring devs go the the spring initializer application at start.spring.io and configure the project there.

There are numerous advantages of using spring initializr

1. You can see the different dependencies you don't need to remember their group and artifact Id .
2. The necessary folders automatically get generated .
3. It is a less time consuming thing
4. You can easily edit the pom.xml later

Have a good day . Happy learning